# csplit regex with pipe (|)

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, split, csplit

i want to split file by regular expression, i have file format as below

```
0|t| lorem ...
some text 
138|t| title 
some text
```

if i execute `egrep "[0-9]+\|t\|" file | wc -l` it counts occurrence correctly but if i execute `csplit filename /[0-9]+\|t\|/` then it says no match found and does not split file.

seems some issue with pipe in pattern but not able to figure out solution.

Comment: Put it in quotes.  `csplit filename '/[0-9]+\|t\|/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must realize that `csplit` regexes are [Basic Regular Expressions (BRE)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) and hence would not understand the `+` `\|` etc.

Just do this:

```
csplit yourfile '%^[0-9]*|t|%' '/^[0-9]*|t|/' '{*}'
```

Then look for files named `xxNN` in your current directory.

Comment: BRE: basic regular expressions. Like those supported by sed, grep, and awk: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions